# why are my contours not being totally filled in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am processing video that looks like this (these are moving blobs):

[image]

I am successfully able to do basic processing in opencv to find contours around the blobs, draw circles around them, etc.  Below is some tracking info drawn over an inverted image of the original video frame:

[image]

I would like to do a projection of these moving blob sequences, such that I get an image with a black trace of the blobs movement.  I call this a blob track.  I think I'm using the term "projection" correctly, because if this was a 3d stack it would be called a "z-projection" (only the projection this time is through time/frames in the video).

When I do this, I get an image of the blob track that is close to what I want, but there are tiny green pixels inside that I do not expect to be there considering I am filling a contour with black and then merging these filled contours.  I get something like this:

[image]

Note the small green pixels present inside the blob track.  They might seem subtle, but I don't want them there and can't figure out why they are there considering all I am doing in the code is stamping black blobs on top of one-another.  The fact that they are green implies to me that they are part of the green background image on which I draw the blob tracks.

I know my filling is working because if I take a single frame instead of making a blob-track I get this, which looks good:

[image]

Something must be going wrong with the way I am doing the projection (addition of the filled contours through time).

The code for the single frame (working and shown up above) is:

```
cv2.drawContours(contourimage,bigbadlistofcontours[0],-1,(0,0,0),-1)
```

where `contourimage` is a green image the size of my frame, and bigbadlistofcontours[0] is the first entry in a list of my contours, and as you can see bigbadlistofcontours[0] contains *two contours*, which represent the *two blobs*, drawn successfully above.

The code for adding/projecting the multiple frames (not working and having these small green pixels inside) is:

```
for xx in bigbadlistofcontours:
    cv2.drawContours(contourimage,xx[0],-1,(0,0,0),-1)
    cv2.drawContours(contourimage,xx[1],-1,(0,0,0),-1)
    #cv2.fillPoly(contourimage, pts =xx[0], color=(0,0,0))
    #cv2.fillPoly(contourimage, pts =xx[1], color=(0,0,0))
```

As you can see I tried it using two methods - one using drawContours, and the other using fillPoly.  Both produce small pixels inside the blob track that should not be there.  Any idea what could cause these pixels to be there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a small correction to your code and try below code:

```
for xx in bigbadlistofcontours:
    cv2.drawContours(contourimage,[xx[0]],-1,(0,0,0),-1)
    cv2.drawContours(contourimage,[xx[1]],-1,(0,0,0),-1)
```

Or simply try the following:

```
for xx in bigbadlistofcontours:
    cv2.drawContours(contourimage,xx,-1,(0,0,0),-1)
```

`findContours` needs a list of contours as arguments, ie a list of numpy arrays. When you passed `bigbadlistofcontours[0]`, it was a list of two numpy arrays ie, two contours. But when you pass `xx` the second time, you passed `xx[0]` which is a numpy array and `xx[1]` which is another numpy array. In that case, it will draw only a point in that numpy array, not full contours.

[More Details on Contours](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html#table-of-content-contours)